# PHP Quiz system with users and answers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Gonna try to explain my problem, sorry for my bad English :)

Im busy with an Quiz system.

So what tables like:

```
- Users
- Question
- Answers
- Sended Answers
```

The users table is not realy necessary for my question.

Questions table is like:

```
- Questions.ID
- Question.Text (the question)
```

Answers Table is like:

```
- Answers.ID
- Answers.QuestionID
- Answers.Text
- Answers.Good
```

Sended Answers table is like:

```
- sAnswers.ID
- sAnswers.QuestionID
- sAnswers.FilledAnswers
- sAnswers.UserID
```

Answers.Good is like 0 = Not good / 1 = Good.

What is that i get all the Sended Answers with UsersName and Find if the sAnswers is good yes or not.

I tried:

```
public function countScores($bind=""){
  $sql = "SELECT sAnswers.*, users.name, Answers.*
  FROM sAnswers
  INNER JOIN users ON sAnswers.userID = users.id
  INNER JOIN Answers ON sAnswers.FilledAnswers = Answers.QuestionID";
  $result = $this->run($sql,$bind);
  return $result;
}
```

But the results are more than sAwnsers have.
What am i doing wrong :-o

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you schema design is, but just guessing, your join on answers should be Answers.ID like this

```
INNER JOIN users ON sAnswers.userID = users.id
INNER JOIN Answers ON sAnswers.FilledAnswers = Answers.ID";
```

Are you sure inner join would work in your case, i.e if all the tables are filled, try doing left join just to be safe

```
LEFT JOIN users ON sAnswers.userID = users.id
LEFT JOIN Answers ON sAnswers.FilledAnswers = Answers.ID
```

Comment: I agree, based on what was shown in the question it looks like it should be `Answers.ID` instead.

Comment: I have tried it. But than it shows too much results. If someone answers 3 questions and i watch the results than i get 9 rows. That means there where 3 questions and two answers and thats 9. But what i want is to show only 3 sended answers.